# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex' Error still shows of when in try-catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin forms project, and there is a piece of code where I want to navigate to another page. The error still shows up even though I put that piece of code inside a try-catch. Heres that code:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new QuestionPage(int.Parse(FromLection.SelectedItem.ToString()),
                int.Parse(ToLection.SelectedItem.ToString()), questionTypeAsInt));
```

there's nothing that can be zero, because the FromLection and ToLection are pickers and I check before that none of them are empty. What could cause that error?
(EDIT)
Here is an image:[image: (I know might be hard to understand because it's in german)]
I can translate if needed

Comment: Are you sure this code is throwing the exception? You can check the origin of the exception

Comment: try using a try-catch in a wider scope and look if it catches some other exception

Comment: *there's nothing that can be zero* - screenshot please

Comment: @antoprd or turn on "break when thrown"

Comment: I have that enabled, it doesn't show me where de error came from, but I debugged and it always threw at that exact spot

Comment: It now throws the error after it navigated to that page, on my device i can see the title of the new page but all the elements of the page before that are still there

Comment: Show the stack trace at the time of the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In your 'watch' Tab ('Überwachen' in German) there are two watches for a parameter named 'startIndex' that seems to be out of index because it's negative. Is that your code or framework code?

Comment: I'm too stupid, I dont know what a stack trace is, sorry

Comment: StackTrace is a property of the exception object. Its shown in the Exception Dialog. It contains the call stack of the code that throws.

Comment: Click on 'Details kopieren' to get the stacktrace

Comment: I'ts framework code, because i never deklared any variables that are called "startIndex"

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  Nachricht = StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex

Comment: ok thanks. Does that happen on a transition from one page to another?
My guess is that some Selector (Combo, ListBox, TabControl) is either loaded or unloaded and temporarily has a SelectedIndex of -1 and you have some code that evaluates the selection, which only works when all UI is completely loaded (and index is 0 or positive).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239427/discussion-between-daskeksschwert3-and-lidqy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution: at the transition to a new Page the elements on the first page unload, causing the "selectedIndex" of pickers to be -1 (Nothing selected) Solution: create a variable and save the values of the pickers in it and then give these to the constructor of the new page. credits to @lidqy